# Is there a way to reduce the height of TextFormField widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

This is code of the one `TextFormField`, which is wrap inside a `SizedBox` widget to set the 
height of the `TextFormField` but shrinks when validation message appears below the `TextFormField`.

```
Widget _firstNameField() {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 35,
      child: TextFormField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
        validator: _validateFirstName,
        onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
          FocusScope.of(contextenter code here).requestFocus(lastNameFocusNode);
        },
        onSaved: (value) {
          _firstName = value;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: use contentPadding in decoration of text form field.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change the height of the SizedBox, and thus, the FormField when validation is triggered, you need to:

1) Make sure you are using a StatefulWidget and not a StatelessWidget.

2) Use a variable, call it `_textFormFieldHeight`, and assign it to your initial height, like this:

```
int _textFormFieldHeight = 35

return SizedBox(
      height: _textFormFieldHeight,
```

Whenever your validation code is triggered (somewhere in `_validateFirstName`, call: `setState(() => _textFormFieldHeight = 15);`

And that should do the trick!

Comment: If you just need to shrink your form field a little when there is a validation, this method works great. Alternatively, you can use the decoration property (as suggested by Amit) which has the advantage of allowing you to increase the padding beyond the default should you need to.

`decoration: InputDecoration(contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(_textFormFieldHeight)),`

Comment: I don't want to shrink the text form field but rather stay in its original height mentioned in SizedBox . the problem is clearly visible in the image attached with the question.